# Proper notation to indicate intervals in which a function is increasing

Tags: calculus, functions

I will ask my question with an example. Define $f:[0, 2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = \sin(x)$. This function is increasing in the intervals $(0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and $(\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi)$. My calculus teacher asks that the final answer is expressed by asserting something like "$f(x)$ is increasing in $(0, \frac{\pi}{2}) \cup (\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi)$".

Is this notation precise? According to the Calculus textbook by Apostol, "a function $f$ is said to be increasing on a set $S$ if $f(x) ≤ f(y)$ for every pair of points $x$ and $y$  in $S$ with $x<y$".

If you consider the set $S = (0, \frac{\pi}{2}) \cup (\frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi)$, it is certainly not true that given two numbers $x,y \in S$ $x<y \Longrightarrow f(x) ≤ f(y)$.  Simply consider $x=1$ and $y=6$ as a counterexample.

Therefore I require clarification: how is the final answer best expressed?

Comment: You can rephrase the statement as " f is increasing in the intervals $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $(\frac{3\pi}{2},2\pi)$ separately ".

Comment: I agree with you and disagree with your teacher. That being said, I have encountered the notation he insists on in some books I consider poorly written (by non-mathematicians). I would say $f$ is increasing on the intervals $[0,\pi/2]$ and $[3\pi/2,2\pi]$ and decreasing on $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$.